# R/slackr: How can I setup slackr without legacy tokens?

Tags: r, token, slack, verification

I'm trying to set up some automatized slack channels. All the content is ready and automation should work but I'm having problems with setting up slackr. There is a nice tutorial on slackr [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3402657/how-to-slack-from-r.html) but it is outdated as slack has changed its token styles.

```
dcf_file <- "api_token: [Verification Token]
channel: #bot
username: coronapush
incoming_webhook_url: [webhook_url]
write.dcf(dcf_file, file = "slackr.dcf", )
slackr_setup(config_file = "slackr.dcf", echo = T)
```

However this gives me:

```
{
  "SLACK_CHANNEL": ["NA"],
  "SLACK_USERNAME": ["NA"],
  "SLACK_ICON_EMOJI": ["NA"],
  "SLACK_INCOMING_URL_PREFIX": ["NA"],
  "SLACK_API_TOKEN": ["NA"]
}
```

and

```
slackr_channels()
NULL
```

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Found my way. You have to create a .txt file called ".xxx" with the following lines:

```
api_token: xxx
channel: xxx
username: xxx
incoming_webhook_url: xxx
```

Then slackr_setup(config_file ="[path/]xxx", echo =T) should give you something like this:

```
{
  "SLACK_CHANNEL": ["#general"],
  "SLACK_USERNAME": ["slackr"],
  "SLACK_ICON_EMOJI": [""],
  "SLACK_INCOMING_URL_PREFIX": [""],
  "SLACK_API_TOKEN": [""]
}
```

**Most important: slackr_msg() does not work.** You have to use slackr_bot(). That is a bit annoying if it takes you forever to find it out like it did for me. Probably you (if you read this far =)) and I should just learn to work with the API directly.

Comment: Did you ever get slack_bot to post to a channel that the original webhook did not point to? For me it ignores the slack channel argument and just posts directly to me which is how I set up the webhook.

Comment: I'm having the same issue @LionelDuarte

Comment: I think you have to set up a new webhook for every channel.